# Show everyplay redirect to your game page

Tags: redirect, everyplay

When I call the following method `[[Everyplay sharedInstance] showEveryplay]`, if the user is  logged in, it will open directly to their Everyplay Following page or profile page. How do I redirect them to my game page?

Comment: Note, with 0 people following your Tag (consisting of 19 mistagged questions), the fact that you assume everyone knows what language/program/library you're talking about, and the fact that you don't show any resources/attempts you've tried to resolve your issue, you have a really low chance of someone answering your question, as a 1 reputation user.

Comment: Number 1 thing would be to search how would you redirect the users to another page using the language that you're using. Then you will try to create a condition block using `if else` and redirect the user somewhere. And also how would you check that user is not logged in? When you use the code to show him the page! You can create another block that starts from `} else {` and redirect the user to another page usin that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Everyplay iOS documentation is lacking info about the showEveryplayWithPath method. However the [Unity documentation](https://developers.everyplay.com/doc/Everyplay-integration-to-Unity3d-game) has a section 'Interacting with the Everyplay Service' about it.

On iOS you may call:

```
[[Everyplay sharedInstance] showEveryplayWithPath: @"/feed/game"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been been looking for this method's document! Everything works fine now!